# How to send JSON body from API Gateway without using Lambda in CDK

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

**Is there a way to send JSON body as response for 'GET' method in AWS API Gateway *without* using AWS Lambda.** Here JSON is constant. It will be same every time this 'GET' method is called that why I don't want create a Lambda for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your use case is ideal for mock API integration - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-mock-integration.html

Answer (score 3):

```
this.restApi.root.addResource("test").addMethod("GET", new MockIntegration({
        requestTemplates: {
            'application/json': `{"statusCode" : 200}`
        },
        integrationResponses: [
            {
                statusCode: '200',
                responseTemplates: { 'application/json': `{"name": "John"}` }
            }
        ]
    }), {
        methodResponses: [
            {
                statusCode: '200',
                responseModels: { 'application/json': Model.EMPTY_MODEL }
            }
        ]
    });
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).